# hide a tag href value in the browser

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using html a tag as follow.

```
<a href="javascript:MyFunction("MyParamValue")">My Link</a>
```

Based on it, when user mouse over link text `"My Link"`, browser status bar shows `javascript:MyFunction("MyParamValue")`. I am just wondering if there is anyway of not showing `javascript:MyFunction("MyParamValue")` to the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyFunction(..)">My Link</a>
```

Or even better:

```
<a href="#" id="my-link">My Link</a>
```

and somewhere in a JS block:

```
$('#my-link').click(function() {
  //your function
});
```

Comment: Definitely this. +1. You don't want to include the javascript as the href itself. Go with the separation of script and markup.

Comment: `onclick` is pretty nasty - don't be mixing behaviour into your markup.

Answer (score 1):

The old school method of changing the status bar was simply:

```
<a href="#" onclick="My..." onmouseover="window.status='some text';">blah</a>
```

However, this has since been deprecated and must be explicitly turned on in settings by the user. It still works in Opera I think.

The method I would use would be to make the href have the text you want to display, and then return false during the onclick:

```
<a href="Pretty status bar text" onclick="MyFunction('blah'); return false;">blah</a>
```